# Updating Multiple Columns from another table - Need Oracle format

Tags: sql-update, oracle9i

I have a script that I use in SQL Server but I need to convert it to an Oracle format. Can anyone help?

```
    UPDATE PERSONS P SET 
        P.JOBTITLE=TE.JOBTITLE,
        P.LAST_NAME=TE.LAST_NAME,
        P.FIRST_NAME=TE.FIRST_NAME,
        P.DBLOGIN_ID=TE.DBLOGIN_ID,
        P.EMAIL_ID=TE.EMAIL_ID,
        P.USERLEVEL=TE.USERLEVEL,
        P.FACILITY_ID=TE.FACILITY_ID,
        P.SUPERVISOR=TE.SUPERVISOR,
        P.DEPARTMENT=TE.DEPARTMENT,
        P.WINLOGINID=TE.WINLOGINID
   FROM TEMP_ECOLAB_PERSONS TE
   WHERE P.PERSON=TE.PERSON;
```

--From the article below I came up with the following statement. It still doesn't work unfortunately:

```
  UPDATE (SELECT P.JOBTITLE, P.LAST_NAME, P.FIRST_NAME, P.DBLOGIN_ID, P.EMAIL_ID,
        P.USERLEVEL, P.FACILITY_ID, P.SUPERVISOR, P.DEPARTMENT,
        TE.JOBTITLE, TE.LAST_NAME, TE.FIRST_NAME, TE.DBLOGIN_ID, TE.EMAIL_ID,
        TE.USERLEVEL, TE.FACILITY_ID, TE.SUPERVISOR, TE.DEPARTMENT
     FROM PERSONS P, TEMP_ECOLAB_PERSONS TE WHERE P.PERSON=TE.PERSON)
  SET 
     P.JOBTITLE=TE.JOBTITLE,
     P.LAST_NAME=TE.LAST_NAME,
     P.FIRST_NAME=TE.FIRST_NAME,
     P.DBLOGIN_ID=TE.DBLOGIN_ID,
     P.EMAIL_ID=TE.EMAIL_ID,
     P.USERLEVEL=TE.USERLEVEL,
     P.FACILITY_ID=TE.FACILITY_ID,
     P.SUPERVISOR=TE.SUPERVISOR,
     P.DEPARTMENT=TE.DEPARTMENT;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I would do it.  It might not be the best performance, but it works.

```
MERGE INTO PERSONS_TMP PT
USING ( 
    SELECT P.PERSON, P.JOB_TITLE, P.FIRST_NAME, P.LAST_NAME, P.FACILITY_ID 
    FROM PERSONS P) TMP
ON (PT.PERSON = TMP.PERSON)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET 
    PT.FACILITY_ID = TMP.FACILITY_ID, 
    PT.JOB_TITLE = TMP.JOB_TITLE,
    PT.FIRST_NAME = TMP.FIRST_NAME,
    PT.LAST_NAME = TMP.LAST_NAME;
```

The script above will update information in PERSONS_TMP table using data from PERSONS table.  I believe in your case, you want it the other way around.  So, please make sure you make the necessary changes before running the script.

You can add "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN.... " clause to the above SQL in case you need to insert new records, if it does not exist.

Comment: I added what (I think) the article said to do above. Still doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the link to Tom's website.  I tried the script from Tom's website and it didn't work either.  So, I removed the link to his website.

Answer (score 25):

```
UPDATE PERSONS P
   SET (jobtitle, 
        last_name, 
        first_name, 
        dblogin_id, 
        email_Id, 
        userlevel, 
        facility_id, 
        supervisor, 
        department, 
        winloginid) = (select jobtitle, 
                              last_name, 
                              first_name, 
                              dblogin_id, 
                              email_Id, 
                              userlevel, 
                              facility_id, 
                              supervisor,  
                              department, 
                              winloginid
                        from  TEMP_ECOLAB_PERSONS TE
                       where TE.PERSON=P.PERSON);
```

Note that if there are other rows present in persons that are not in temp_ecolab_persons, these extra rows in the person table will be set to null (or could cause the statement to fail with not null constraint error by the update above so if this is the case, you may also need a where clause on the update statement to restrict these, e.g. if i know the email_id field is populated on some records but not on others, i can limit the update to just those rows as follows

```
UPDATE PERSONS P
  SET (jobtitle, 
       last_name, 
       first_name, 
       dblogin_id, 
       email_Id, 
       userlevel, 
       facility_id, 
       supervisor, 
       department, 
       winloginid) = (select jobtitle, 
                             last_name, 
                             first_name, 
                             dblogin_id, 
                             email_Id, 
                             userlevel, 
                             facility_id, 
                             supervisor,  
                             department, 
                             winloginid
                       from  TEMP_ECOLAB_PERSONS TE
                      where TE.PERSON=P.PERSON)
   WHERE email_id is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use

```
Where exists (select 1  from  TEMP_ECOLAB_PERSONS TE
                      where TE.PERSON=P.PERSON)
```

Comment: Hi Subhojyoti! Your "answer" looks like more of a comment to perhaps complement an already existing answer. In that case, I would suggest that you add it as a comment to the existing answer. If people consider it useful they will upvote the comment and perhaps even the original author of the answer will update his or her answer with your contribution.

Comment: Please describe solution. For advice, please answer with comment.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT THIS ERROR WHEN TRYING TO DO THE FOLLOWING :

```
UPDATE TABLE A SET (A.COLUMN1 , A.COLUMN2) = (SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2 FROM DUAL) WHERE A.KEY = :VARIABLE;
```

WHEN CHANGE TO :

```
UPDATE TABLE A SET A.COLUMN1 = VALUE1, A.COLUMN2 = VALUE2 WHERE A.KEY = :VARIABLE;
```

EVERY THING IS OK.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING???